# Flutter not able to run, get_navigation & theme error

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter, macos-catalina

i'm actually trying to run my app but i'm stucked with that error :

```
Running "flutter pub get" in riverpod_stacked_app...
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.15.0/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:235:37: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
    final theme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:119:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.15.0/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:431:43: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
      theme: Theme.of(key.currentContext, shadowThemeOnly: true),
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:119:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/Alex/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 900

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/Alex/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I don't understand why it can't build. I don't see the link between those 2 errors :

- get_navigation
- something with the theme from material.dart
  And my actual motivation to use riverpod, stacked_services and firebase.

Here is the result of flutter doctor -v :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.98, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-8.0.pre.98 at /Users/Alex/development/flutter
    • Framework revision ef4ec09a06 (6 hours ago), 2020-11-05 08:02:13 -0800
    • Engine revision bf259226b2
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-21.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Alex/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

And here is my dependencies in pubspeck.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  stacked_services:
  auto_route: 0.6.9
  hooks_riverpod: 0.12.1
  flutter_hooks:

  firebase_core: 0.5.1
  firebase_auth: 0.18.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  auto_route_generator:
```

Any ideas ? I've trie to clean up my dependencies and reinstall. Also i start a blank project with flutter counter app and it runs properly.

Comment: try removing the `.packages` file, running `pub upgrade`, removing `pubspec.lock`, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I also had this problem today after upgrading Flutter.

I was only able to solve it after I deleted that method parameter from the file that triggered the error. You'll have to delete it in two places.

Search in .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.15.0/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart for

```
Theme.of(key.currentContext, shadowThemeOnly: true)
```

As replace it with

```
Theme.of(key.currentContext)
```

This is probably cause by the stacked_services dependency that uses the get: ^3.15.0 dependency

Later edit: this is actually not the best solution, because somebody cloning your repo will not be able to compile the project unless they also to this change

So it's better to upgrade the dependency that causes this error, or replace it with another one; but only after you ran flutter upgrade, or try changing the channel

Comment: I remove Stacked and use auto_route ExtendedNavigator and it works. 
Thanks !

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 7):

this is already fixed by getx in 16.1. Pub upgrade will do it

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/762

Comment: this shoud be the accepted answer since it is not a hack

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove only

```
 ThemeData theme = Theme.of(key.currentContext, shadowThemeOnly: false);
    if (theme != null) {
      bottomSheet = new Theme(data: theme, child: bottomSheet);
    }
    return bottomSheet;
```

form your .pubcach folder.