# Flutter/ Firebase Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code,

Tags: flutter

after I update my Xcode, and try to develop web app with flutter , I can not
launch my app on the device, below error is just little parts of start and end point.

I have no idea why this is happening , it's saying a lot of packages are deprecated....

In file included from /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.1+3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestoreUtils.m:5:
In file included from /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.1+3/ios/Classes/Private/FLTFirebaseFirestoreUtils.h:11:

```
   /Users/daegilpyo/AndroidStudioProjects/eminail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:75:10: warning: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]
            #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
             ^
    1 warning generated.
```

like this...

is there any solution for this problem ?

```
Running "flutter pub get" in eminail...
Launching lib/main.dart on DAEGIL의 iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: T6ULPGT4J7
Xcode build done.                                           170.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.7.1/ios/Classes/SwiftVibrationPlugin.swift:39:13: warning: switch must be exhaustive
                switch reason {
                ^
    /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibration-1.7.1/ios/Classes/SwiftVibrationPlugin.swift:39:13: note: do you want to add missing cases?
                switch reason {
                ^
    /Users/daegilpyo/AndroidStudioProjects/eminail/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/daegilpyo/AndroidStudioProjects/eminail/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:119:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on DAEGIL의 iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706160/flutter-not-able-to-run-get-navigation-theme-error, So basically upgrading should do the trick

Comment: Concerning the two first errors, you should enumerate all the possible keys enumerated in your enum to remove this warning. For the last errors, you may try to upgrade your packages in pubspec.yaml file and then flutter clean.